# How do I mount whole docker image as volume in host?

Tags: docker, docker-image, mounted-volumes

I'd like to mount a whole docker image as a volume in the host.  I could run the image, but I don't really need to, I just need the files to be visible as files within a directory/volume/mount point outside of docker.

(To be clear, I don't need to mount a host directory as a volume in a running docker instance which is what `docker run -v` does; I need the opposite, to mount a directory in the docker image or the whole image as a volume in the host; read-only is okay)

Comment: It will be easier running the image.

Comment: @KamilCuk okay, supposing I do run the image, how do I see all the files in it from outside the image?

Comment: There is no interface to do that. You can: find the PID of the process outside the image, list `/proc/$PID/mounts` to get the root mountpoint, then navigate to that mountpoint to see the files. And this just depends on the storage driver you use. On my system, I have btrfs, which uses [/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes](https://github.com/saturnism/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver.md). But that's _my system_, you can have something completely different.

Comment: You might be able to run a SMB or NFS server container. Map your volume to it and then use SMB or NFS to mount it on the host.

Comment: Where is Docker actually involved in this?  Can you just `mkdir` a host directory and copy content into it, if you're not going to run a process?  Or can you create an archive like a tar file instead of a Docker image?

Comment: @DavidMaze The image already exists, I need to use files from it; it's easiest if it's mounted.  "create an archive like a tar file" - that doesn't solve the problem of trying to access the contents of an already existing image from outside the image, since it needs to be done at creation time (and can't be done from a Dockerfile per se)

Comment: Note that this may lead to possible filesystem mismatch issues: https://www.fullstaq.com/knowledge-hub/blogs/docker-and-the-host-filesystem-owner-matching-problem

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz If by mismatch you mean uid/gid issues, I know and I'm not worried about that. Are there any other issues you're thinking of?

Comment: @AlexI I meant filesystem architecture-related issues (see the link above for more info).